# performance testing uwsgi application in microservice

Tags: performance, containers, microservices, uwsgi, grafana

I have my uwsgi application deployed as a container pod in kubernetes which uses cherrypy to expose APIs. I need to evaluate the performance of the container and to set the limits such as CPU and memory.

I am using Grafana to check the CPU and Memory usage.

Container resources requirements as configured below,

**deployment.yaml**

```
resources:
   requests:
     memory: 256Mi
     cpu: 100m
   limits:
     memory: 512Mi
     cpu: 200m
```

I am using locust to post requests parallely to check the limit of requests and other metrics but i am observing some thing very different.

```
import invokust
url = "http://<node_ipaddress>:<node_port>/config/"
settings = invokust.create_settings(
    locustfile='locust_file.py',
    host=url,
    num_clients=500,
    hatch_rate=500,
    run_time='1m'
)
load_test = invokust.LocustLoadTest(settings)
load_test.run()
load_test.stats()
```

**locust_file.py**

```
users = {'name': 'abc'}

class UserTasks(TaskSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserTasks, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.payload = users 

    def on_start(self):
        pass

    @task
    def index(self):
        response = self.client.post("/SRVCC/Global",data=self.payload)
        print(response.status_code)
        assert_that(200).is_equal_to(response.status_code)
        print("Successfully added user")

class User(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserTasks
    min_wait = 100000
    max_wait = 200000
```

I ran with 100 users, it works fine without error. Later i increased to 500 users and some of the requests are failed with status code 0.

When i checked the CPU and memory usage in Grafana i dont see any problem in CPU and memory which is well within the limit configured.

I could not understand the why the some of the requests are failing even when resources requirements are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason you were using invokust instead of using locust natively?

It'd be useful to include the following info as well, based on your question, it's impossible to determine the answer.

- version of locust and invokust used
- how did you invoke the load tests
- exact output of your script

Even if you use locust directly, I'd recommend some tweaks:

1. It looks like you have quite a long min wait-time, which means your users are not very active. Try reduce the wait time and decrease the number of users.
2. Hatching 500 users per second is pretty intense and your machine may struggle with it. Try ramping up gradually. https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-in-step-load-mode.html